# Updating of mysql database via java

Tags: java, mysql

I have a program that will update every one minute. Each time it updates, it will either add the time, date, demand, or it will update the demand according to the same time and date. However, my current code does not allow me to do that. I've tried add another code to rectify this problem, but it doesn't work. Does anyone know how to add a constraint so that when it encounters the same data and time, but different demand, it will just update the db with the new demand. Instead of adding a new row, which contains the same time and date but different demand.

My original code:

```
preparedStatement = connect
.prepareStatement("insert into  testdb.emcsg values (?, ?, ? , ?, ?)");
preparedStatement.setInt(1, count+1);
preparedStatement.setString(2, d1);
preparedStatement.setString(3, d2);
preparedStatement.setString(4, d3);
preparedStatement.setString(5, d4);
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

My edited code:

```
preparedStatement = connect
.prepareStatement("insert INTO testdb.emcsg values (?, ?, ? , ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 5");
preparedStatement.setInt(1, count+1);
preparedStatement.setString(2, d1);
preparedStatement.setString(3, d2);
preparedStatement.setString(4, d3);
preparedStatement.setString(5, d4);
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

This edited code came out with an error "You have an error in your SQL syntax;" Advice and help will be appreciated!

Comment: Is there more of the error you can post?

Comment: Did you check the syntax by manually executing a test query in the mysql console?

Comment: Hi, no, I used the syntax provided on this website http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '5' at line 1
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)

Answer (score 3):

[The documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) shows that you must have an assignment at the end of the clause:

```
insert into  testdb.emcsg (a, b, c, d, e) values (?, ?, ? , ?, ?) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE e = ?
```

Note that it's a good practice to list the column names in an insert statement, rather than relying on the order they were defined, and on the maintainer to know this order.

Comment: Hi JB Nizet, thanks for the prompt reply. I have a question to ask. This is updating is only possible on condition that one primary key is not duplicated with the same data. However, in my case, I want to set 3 keys must be the same, or else, the thing will be updated. Is it possible?

Comment: If you have a unique index on this tuple, it should work. Or you could just issue a select query, and insert or update depending on the result of the select.

Comment: Hmm..I'm still not able to get it. Maybe I could illustrate this out:
Date   Time          Demand
01-Jan 01:00-02:00   500
01-Jan 02:00-03:00   600

However, I'm adding a new data, a new demand value
01-Jan 01:00-02:00 700

I want the system to update with the new demand value. However, it must be able to differentiate which row to update. In this case, there's a need for 2 unique key?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) it seems that you might need to reference the column name(s) you want to update. For instance (a,b,c,d,e should be replaced by your actual column names):

```
preparedStatement = connect
.prepareStatement("insert INTO testdb.emcsg(a,b,c,d,e) values (?, ?, ? , ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE e=VALUES(e)");
preparedStatement.setInt(1, count+1);
preparedStatement.setString(2, d1);
preparedStatement.setString(3, d2);
preparedStatement.setString(4, d3);
preparedStatement.setString(5, d4);
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```